# Axis2 webservice (aar archive) properties file

Tags: java, properties, web-services, weblogic, apache-axis

I'm currently developing a set of SOAP webservices over *Axis2*, deployed over a clustered *WebLogic* 10.3.2 environment.

My webservices use some user settings that I want to be editable without the need for recompiling and regenerating the AAR archive. With this in mind, I chose to put them into a `properties` file that is loaded and consumed in runtime.

Unfortunately, I'm having some questions about this:

As far as I know, to achieve what I want, the only option is to put the properties file into the `../axis2/WEB-INF/classes` directory of each one of the deployments (on each *WebLogic* instance) I currently have on my clustered configuration, and then load the file, as follows (or equivalent, this has not been verified for optimization):

```
InputStreamReader fMainProp = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties"));
Properties mainProp = new Properties();
mainProp.load(fMainProp);
```

This is not as practical as I wanted it to be, because each time I want to alter some setting on the properties file, I have to edit each one of the files (deployed over different *WebLogic* instances) and there is a high probability of modifying one of these files without modifying the others.

What I would like to know is if there is any (better) alternative to accomplish what I want, minimizing the potential conflict of configuration that is created by distributing and replicating the properties file through multiple *WebLogic* instances.

Comment: Assume your platform cannot be set up with a common shared mount to deploy the AAR on?

Comment: I was thinking of a complicated solution. 
Assuming the values you read will be cached within the server rather than read from file each time, and implement a cluster-aware cache to flush any time the file is re-read.

Comment: Perhaps you should use JNDI, then configure your applications properties using the console provided by you app server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usecase suits use of JMX.

Please see this link for details of using JMX to build custom Mbeans to manage application configurations.
http://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/2009/10/developing_custom_mbeans_to_ma.html

Then you can either opt for console or WLST script based access.

Comment: @saks, will the MBean server be per instance or available as common across the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a System Variable in the `Weblogic` to hold on the absolute property file location. At the weblogic installation you will find `setDomainEnv.cmd` (Windows) or `setDomainEnv.sh` (Linux). Inside that add (append) to `JAVA_OPTIONS` the system variable you need. For example

```
-DpropLocation=C:/somewhere/The.properties
```

In your code you can get the property file location by `System.getProperties("propLocation").` You can add multiple System variable by adding spaces in between them.